# FUNCION que retorne un arreglo con cada elemento multiplicado por 3

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito hacer una función que reciba un arreglo de números como parámetro y retorne un nuevo arreglo con cada elemento triplicado

Ejemplo:

```
triplicar([3, 9, 10, 15]) // retorna [9, 27, 30, 45]
duplicar([1, 5, 11]) // retorna [3, 15, 33]
```

Esto he intentado:

```js
function trplicar(arreglo) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    return 3*arreglo[i];
 }
}

console.log(triplicar([3, 12, 45, 7]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Cuando pones un `return` la función retorna el valor y no continua. Es decir, la función se detiene en ese punto, por lo que tu función solo alcanza a iterar una sola vez.

Existen varias formas de hacer esto:

**1.- Simple Mutable**

Se toma el mismo arreglo y se multiplica, esta opción **modifica el arreglo original**

```js
let arreglo_original = [3, 12, 45, 7];

function trplicar(arreglo) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    arreglo[i]*=3;
 }
}

console.log(arreglo_original);
trplicar(arreglo_original);
console.log(arreglo_original);
```

**2.- Simple inmutable**

Esta opción crea un nuevo arreglo, sin modificar el original. Para esto debes crear un nuevo arreglo dentro de la función y retornarla.

Como verás en el siguiente ejemplo, el array original permanece intacto

```js
let arreglo_original = [3, 12, 45, 7];
function trplicar(arreglo) {
 let nuevo_arreglo =[];  
  for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    nuevo_arreglo.push(arreglo[i]*3);
 }
 return nuevo_arreglo;
}

let new_arr = trplicar(arreglo_original);
console.log(new_arr);
console.log(arreglo_original);
```

**3.- Usando [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

Una función map, crea un nuevo arreglo transformando los elementos interiores. Básicamente recorre el array y realiza alguna operación (de cualquier tipo) a cada elemento. En tu caso multiplicar por 3

```js
let arreglo_original = [3, 12, 45, 7];

let nuevo_arreglo = arreglo_original.map(a=>a*3);
console.log(nuevo_arreglo);
console.log(arreglo_original);
```

**4.- Forma ultra rebuscada**

Existe otra manera, que la colocaré solo porque se parece mucho al código que tú has mostrado, que es usando iteradores, pero en vez de usar `return` se usa un `yield`

```js
function* trplicar(arreglo) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    yield 3 * arreglo[i];
 }
}

console.log(Array.from( trplicar([3, 12, 45, 7])));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function trplicar(arreglo) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    return 3*arreglo[i];
 }
}

console.log(triplicar([3, 12, 45, 7]))
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a tu propia pregunta? ¿Cómo funciona? Fijate cómo [en esta respuesta](/a/577474) explican detalladamente el código. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución al reto:

```
function multiplicarArreglo(arreglo, multiplicador) {
  return arreglo.map((num) => num * multiplicador);
}

console.log(multiplicarArreglo([1,2,3,4], 2));
console.log(multiplicarArreglo([1,2,3,4], 3));
console.log(multiplicarArreglo([1,2,3,4], 4));
```

Comment: ¿Cómo responde este código a la pregunta? Lee [answer].